# A question regarding gerundive verbs

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Are these affirmations correct ?

I have a diploma in speaking english.
I have a diploma/degree in nursing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a diploma/degree in Nursing.

Yes, that is correct.

> I have a diploma/degree in speaking english.

While that doesn't appear grammatically incorrect, necessarily, there aren't diplomas in "speaking English" which I have ever heard of. The degree would be in "English Literature", or perhaps "English", or "English Philology".  Almost all diplomas and degrees have a certain official form about them.  "Speaking english" is just a casual phrase, instead of an official title.